# Wrong rotation angle when converted to cartesian coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas, degrees, cartesian-coordinates, radians

After some pause decided to convert my small hobby project (3D physics with top-down view) to use Cartesian system instead of using the screen coordinates. Everything just went fine when found that drawing the circle is not correct - its radius is drawn opposite of the direction of movement, for example if the circle's heading South-East, the radius line is drawn pointing North-West.
This is the function which draws the circle:

```
mainWindow.Context.ellipse(drawX, //The x axis of the coordinate for the ellipse's center
                           drawY, //The y axis of the coordinate for the ellipse's center
                           5, //X-radius
                           5, //Y-radius
                           heading * (PI/180), //converted to radians
                           0, //starting point
                           2*PI, //ends, in radians
                           false); //draw in clockwise direction
```

While var heading is calculated with atan2(y, x) and directly converted to Degrees with `heading = heading * (180/PI)`, I'm not sure I should convert it properly back to radians (`ellipse()` tooks only radians as parameter)

Any ideas where's my mistake?
How I'm calculating the heading:

```
angle = atan2(directionY, directionX) * (180 / PI); //to Degrees
if (heading - angle >= error) { heading = heading - (turnRate * PowerToWeightRatio); } 
else { heading = heading + (turnRate * PowerToWeightRatio); }
```

And yes - that was my first try to make a correction, adding or subtracting 180 degrees didn't help, and this looks more like a temporary fix than a permanent solution :(

Comment: Can you show us how you calculate your heading? Intuition tells me you are missing a sign in your y-coordinate. But this is easier to solve by experiment than by reason. If your heading are consistently off by 180 degrees, why not consistently correct that?

Comment: Heading is 0 and gradually changed to be equal to the angle between the circle and a given static point in the coordinate system, code was added in the question

Comment: You likely know this, but check your `directionY` variable... remember that browser position Y and cartesian Y are opposites.

Comment: Yep, it's ok there, convertion from cartesian to screen is fine since the surrounding scenery will be drawn at wrong screen coordinates

Comment: Where does x/y for atan2 come from? If a diff (or vector) try to change order of how they are subtracted (0-y). I would recommend using radians in all steps as all math and draw methods dealing with angles are in radians.

Comment: x and y come from current position of the object (values are correct, checked them with pen and paper method), and yeah I'm using radians (built-in function uses them), just converting them to degrees to have more precision when running the guidance algorithm